# Writing to online excel from front-end

Tags: javascript, excel

I have a form with several fields (written in React).

By submitting the form, I want the values will be written to an existing Excel file (the Excel file is saved in OneDrive), i.e. each submit will add 1 row to the Excel sheet.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Excel REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-write-to-workbook) to do this.

To add a row, first identify the endpoint for your Excel file, and send a POST request to a URL like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/{sheet-name}:/workbook/tables/Table1/rows/add
```

with a payload similar to:

```
{
  'index': null,
  'values': [
    ['col-1-value', 'col-2-value', ...]
  ]
}
```

Where `index` signifies the offset from the last created row.